# Missing positional arguments? (python help)

Tags: python

I'm creating a program to match a particular year to an Olympic location.

I.e. if the user inputs a year, it finds the location where the Olympic games took place that year (1904 - Athens, Greece..) etc.

It keeps telling me i have positional errors in my code, however:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#29>", line 1, in <module> findLocation()
  TypeError: findLocation() missing 3 required positional arguments:
   'yearList', 'locList', and 'year'
```

Here is my program:

```
def getData():

    print("All the events")
    print("")

    yearList = []
    locList = []

    readFile = open('olympics.txt', 'r')

    for line in readFile:
        year, loc = line.split("\t")
        loc = loc.replace("\n", "")
        yearList.append(year)
        locList.append(loc)

    return yearList,locList


def findLocation(yearList, locList, year):
    i=0
    location=""

    while i<len(locList):
        if yearList[i] == year:
            year = yearList[i]
        elif yearList[i] !=year:
            return print ("That was incorrect")

        i += 1

    return location
```

Getting data works successfully, but my `findLocation` function seems to be out of whack and i dont know how to fix it.

Here is an excerpt of the text file containing the Olympic events.

```
1896    Athens, Greece 
1900    Paris, France 
1904    St. Louis, Missouri USA 
1906    Athens, Greece* 
1908    London, England 
1912    Stockholm, Sweden 
1916    Not held** 
1920    Antwerp, Belgium
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: `my findLocation function seems to be out of whack ` isn't helping much :(

Comment: What do you mean positional errors? Can you provide the error message (stacktrace)?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#29>", line 1, in <module>
    findLocation()
TypeError: findLocation() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'yearList', 'locList', and 'year'

Comment: @GeorgeA you never showed the code where you call `findLocation`.

Comment: @GeorgeA beat me to it.. the problem is probably in how you call "findLocation".. please provide additional code.

Comment: def findLocation(yearList, locList,year):
    i=0
    location=""

    while i<len(locList):
        if yearList[i] == year:
            year = yearList[i]
        elif yearList[i] !=year:
            return print ("That was incorrect")

        i += 1
    
   
     

    return location 





def main():
    yearList,Loclist = findLocation()
    choice = getChoice()
    while choice != 2:
        if choice == 1:
            year = input("Enter the year to search for: ")
            loc = findLocation(yearList,locList,year)
            print("The Location for this year was ", loc)

Comment: If that is different from what's in the question, please update your question.  As you can see, code in comments doesn't really work.

Comment: @GeorgeA please update your question

Answer (score 0):

The reason findLocation does not yield a result is because you are iterating over all the years/locations, and if the first one is incorrect you *return* from the function (**return print ("That was incorrect")**)

**UPDATE: Included an example main method describing how to call the functions**

Something like this should work better:

```
def getData():
    print("All the events")
    year_to_location = {}
    with open('olympics.txt', 'r') as f:
        content = f.readlines()
        for line in content:
            year, loc = line.split("\t")
            year_to_location[year] = loc.strip()
    return year_to_location

def findLocation(year_to_location, year):
    if year in year_to_location:
        return year_to_location[year]
    else:
        print("That was incorrect")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    year_to_location = getData()
    print(findLocation(year_to_location, "1900"))
```

Note: I replaced the year_list and loc_list with a dictionary year_to_location instead and simplified the findLocation quite a bit. I also added a with open('olympics.txt') as f statement which is a slightly better way of handling files (it assures that the file handler gets closed when done)

You could also just remove **return** from **return print ("That was incorrect")** and your code should work as is.

Answer (score 0):

> but my findLocation function seems to be out of whack

You are right about that. Your logic needs to be changed there. However, next time, please add a little more information of what you expected and what you got. That will help us. Now on to the logic:

```
def findLocation(yearList, locList, year):
    i=0
    location=""

    while i<len(locList):
        if yearList[i] == year:
            return locList[i]
        elif int(yearList[i]) > int(year):
            print "That was incorrect"
            return

        i += 1
    print "Year was incorrect"
    return
```

Now this function needs to be called with three arguments. Two from your getdata and one from the user to print the location:

year_list, loc_list = getData()
year = raw_input("Enter the year to search:")
findLocation(year_list, loc_list, year)

Answer (score 0):

Having said that your code is *non idiomatic* and that it could be rewritten in a shorter, clearer way, let's try to analyze your problem.

Your error is motivated by a mismatch between the function signature and your usage, but even if it was called correctly it won't return the correct `location`... this is your code

```
def findLocation(yearList, locList, year):
    i=0
    location=""
```

in the line above you set `location`, and it is never reassigned, so you're going to return the null string, irrispective of the rest of your code

```
    while i<len(locList):
        if yearList[i] == year:
            year = yearList[i]
```

the test above is tautological, if two objects are equal (i.e., their values are equal) you assign one's value to the other object... you've not changed anything

```
        elif yearList[i] !=year:
            return print ("That was incorrect")
```

the test above is not what you want, because `1.` you don't want to exit from your function until you've tested all the possible Olympyc years and `2.` `return print(...)` returns the value returned by the `print` function, i.r., `None`.

```
        i += 1
    return location
```

---

Staying close to your coding style, I'd go like this

```
def find_location(y_list, l_list, year):
    i = 0
    while i<len(y_list):
        if year == y_list[i]:
            # the following statement exits the function,
            # returning the Olympics location for the year
            return l_list[i]
        i = i+1
    return ''
```

If you know about the `zip` builtin, the following is more compact and expressive

```
    def f(y_l, l_l, year):
        for y, l in zip(y_l, l_l):
            if year==y: return l
        return ""
```

The real solution of your problem is to use a different data structure instead of the paired lists, namely a `dict` but it seems to me that you were not introduced to it...